Mail merge Word doc from excel need a variable sheet name
I have about 30 different sheets in a workbook with certificate data and each sheet has a word doc that relates to that sheet and I'm trying to make this one macro work on every sheet using the active selection for its mail merge. I have figured out how to get the word doc name as variable by putting the files name in cell A2 as they are all in same folder. I have also got the active sheets name but I cant figure out how to put it into code.
Sub DoMailMerge()
'Note: A VBA Reference to the Word Object Model is required, via Tools|References
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    Dim r As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nLastColumn As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long, nFirstColumn As Long
    Set r = Selection
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 2
    nFirstRow = r.Row - 1
    Dim WFile As String
    WFile = Range("A2").Value
    Dim sheetname As String
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    
With wdApp
  'Disable alerts to prevent an SQL prompt
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  'Open the mailmerge main document
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("C:\Users\Todd\Desktop\" & WFile, _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentfiles:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      'Define the mailmerge type
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      'Define the output
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      'Connect to the data source
      .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, _
        LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentfiles:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;Data Source=strWorkbookName;" & _
        "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Certificates$`", _
        SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = nFirstRow
        .LastRecord = nLastRow
      End With
      'Excecute the merge
      .Execute
      'Disconnect from the data source
      .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
    End With
    'Close the mailmerge main document
    .Close False
  End With
  'Restore the Word alerts
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  'Display Word and the document
  .Visible = True
End With
End Sub

I need to workout how to replace the Certificates part from SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM Certificates$", _ part with sheetname
Thankyou

Try SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM \" & sheetname & "$`", _if the sheetCertificates` is ActiveSheet.

Thankyou very much there are so many different ways to refer to the string as part of code its so confusing which one to use where but getting there
